# Find image of $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|},\ z\in\mathbb{C}.$$ What's the image of $f$? (note that f(z) lies in the unit disc)
Also prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Please show your attempt. Note that the absolute value of $f$ is always less than 1.

Comment: I show that the image of f lies in the unit open disc. Are those sets equals?

Comment: What's the domain?

Comment: As the denominator is a real number, greater-than or equal to one, the domain is all complex numbers.

Comment: @DavidPeterson that's a dangerous assumption to make. Just because a function can be defined on a set doesn't mean it need be.

Comment: @Cameron With no defined domain, it is usually accepted to take the largest subset of the working universe such that an expression is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $z$ as a set of circles centered at origin, i.e. $|z|=r$ with $0\le r<\infty$. Then,

$$|f(z)|=\frac{|z|}{1+|z|}=\frac r{1+r}$$

So, for any circle $|z|=r$ of radius $r$, its image $f(z)$ is a concentric circle of radius $\frac r{1+r}$, which satisfies

$$0\le \frac r{1+r} < 1$$

corresponding to $0\le r<\infty$. Thus, the image is an open unit circle and the mapping is homophobic.